# Creating an array of styles in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, styles

For certain reasons I need to create an array of different styles to eventually use at certain times. Regardless I have this bit of code...

```
export const carouselData = {
    cdata: [{
        bgimage: require('Assets/img/Banners/mybanner1.jpg')
    },{
        bgimage: require('Assets/img/Banners/mybanner2.jpg'),
    }]
}
```

...

```
var mySectionStyle
this.props.cdata.cdata.map((carouselData, key) => (
    mySectionStyle[key] = {
        backgroundImage: "url(" + carouselData.bgimage + ")"
    }
))
return (
    { this.props.cdata.cdata.map((carouselData, key) => (
        <div className="bg_image" style={ sectionStyle[key] }>
            //Some stuff here
        </div>
    ))}
)
```

Now to anyone that is half decent at coding probably sees huge issues with this code but as a newbie I need help finishing it (or rewriting).

Can anyone help me create an array so I can access my styles one by one with `mySectionStyle[0], mySectionStyle[1], mySectionStyle[2]` etc

Edit. I have an array that has many images in it and I want those in an array so I can set the carousel up with different background images.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide an example of the data you have at the moment? Or, how you would like to use the style list?

Comment: Sorry I added more info. I just want to access multi different styles using an array so when I look through all the carousel banners I can assign different background images to them. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do:

```
var mySectionStyle = {
    style1: {
        margin: 0,
    },
    style2: {
        margin: 10,
    },
}

const style1 = mySectionStyle['style1'];
const style2 = mySectionStyle['style2'];
```

If you later need it in an array, you can use the Object methods to convert it.

```
const availableStyles = Object.keys(mySectionStyle); // ['style1', 'style2']

availableStyles.forEach(style => mySectionStyle[style].backgroundImage = `url(${carouselData.bgimage})`;);
```

See also Object.values and Object.entries for other conversion to array options.